# BInding issues with showing Image in xamDataGrid

Tags: wpf, xamdatagrid

I want to show an image in one field of XamDataGrid. 
The path of the Image I have is a property in my `Model`. I was able to Show the image using normal WPF `DataGrid`, but facing issues with XamDataGrid.( see in point 2)

1. Binding ItemImage Property to XamDataGrid Field.

   ```
       <igDP:Field.Settings>
            <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False">
              <igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}" >
                         <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                                     <Grid>
                                        <Image 
                                          Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=                     {x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}}, Path=ItemImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
                                     </Grid>
                                 </ControlTemplate>
                           </Setter.Value>
                         </Setter>
                    </Style>
            </igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
        </igDP:FieldSettings>
      </igDP:Field.Settings>
   ```

   `
2. Working with normal WPF Data Grid.

   ```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ItemImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
             </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   ```

please let me know. if i have to make any change in Step 1.

Comment: You say that one method worked, but in your example code, you have two different `Binding` paths and the first one is missing a part. Please try using the same `Binding` path from the working example in your `XamDataGrid` and come back and complete your first code example if that still doesn't work.

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks for editing help. I have already tried with the binding, Which I have used in Part 2. And then tried to make it through Relative source.Actually Part2 (using simple WPF DataGrid) i tried for experiment only. i Have to use XamDataGrid for the UI.

Answer (score 1):

The DataContext of each field in xamDataGrid is DataRecord object, The property DataItem in it contains your object, so the binding should be defined like so:

```
 <igDP:Field.Settings>
     <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False">
       <igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}" >
                  <Setter Property="Template">
                     <Setter.Value>
                           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                              <Grid>
                                 <Image 
                                   Source="{Binding DataItem.ItemImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
                              </Grid>
                          </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
             </Style>
     </igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
 </igDP:FieldSettings>
```